# Webform populate text component with encoded url values

Tags: webforms, tokens

How to populate a webform component with encoded values. For exampmple my url http://example.com/abc?submitted%5Bthis%5D=1

I tried to use token [current-page:query:this] but it doesnt work.

Answer (score 0):

You're on the right track. It looks like you have a syntax problem with your URL param itself. If you're trying to get the value of `?this`, remove the `sumbitted` and  `[` (%5D) and `]` (%5B). So your URL with the param will look like this:

```
http://example.com/abc?this=1
```

With that URL, `[current-page:query:this]` should return `1` (or `TRUE`).